# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.eng.bt_eng_mobility.viewmodel.HomeViewModelFactory cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, repository, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am getting this error. I have created ViewModelFactory class inside same ViewModel class file.
When Im trying to initialise the viewmodel I am getting this error.

```
//Code written in fragment class in onCreateView after binding code//
homeViewModelFactory = HomeViewModelFactory((requireActivity().application as Application).repository)
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, homeViewModelFactory)
                .get(HomeViewModel::class.java)


//Viewmodelfactoryclass//
class HomeViewModelFactory(private val homeRepository: HomeRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(HomeViewModel::class.java)) {
            return HomeViewModelFactory(homeRepository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `homeViewModelFactory` declared?

Comment: written in onCreateView() method after databinding

Comment: Oh, you're returning a factory from your factory?

Comment: yes right. But its giving class cast exception like I stated above

Comment: The `create` method should create an instance of your view model, not another factory, otherwise we're in an infinite loop of factory creating.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.Factory#create(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The job of the `ViewModelProvider.Factory` is to create instances of your `ViewModel` class. At the moment all you're doing is returning a new instance of your factory.

Instead your return statement should probably be something like this:

```
return HomeViewModel(homeRepository) as T
```

[This article](https://medium.com/koderlabs/viewmodel-with-viewmodelprovider-factory-the-creator-of-viewmodel-8fabfec1aa4f) covers the basics of a `ViewModel` in more detail.